# Which template should i choose for iphone app having multiple pages to view without more memory consumption

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, navigation

I want to develop an app having multiple pages. For example the first page has all menus in it. If you click on one menu it will go to some list page. If you click on some items in the list again it goes to another page with full details of that item and it goes on. In every page there is another menus relevant to that page. If i click on that menu it will take me to that particular page and come back to same page from where i clicked the menu.

I searched through the web and i came across that Navigation-Based template is best to implement this.

I had little concern in memory management point if i navigate from one page to another continuously for more than 3 or 4 pages Navigation-Based approach will keep all the views in the stack which eats lots of memory. Is this a best approach or is there any workaround to implement this kind page navigation.

Whether the Navigation-Based approach will take care of memory problems when i navigate from one page to another. If my understanding is wrong correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you take the memory management part too high.
Why shouldn't you use a predefined function which is used in million other apps?

Or another question which really (and I mean really) big interface which will consume 40 mb of memory? The iPhone is really efficient with it's own UI. Your first part in memory management is to take care of your allocations so that no leaks appear.

The views stay in memory and should stay in memory because no one want to wait a few seconds while navigating from one view to another. (But of course you can remove unnecessary UI elements while of screen)

Comment: I understand but the thing is that if i navigate more number of pages what will be the memory consumption when i use the UINavigationController? In the earlier question i mentioned that i want to navigate more number of pages and moreover in some pages there are some sub menus which will entirely take the user the new page. From that page i dont want to again navigate to previous page but need to come to home page. So i think the views in the memory will not get released.

Answer (score 1):

Do use UINavigationController, it's the best one for your needs.

And also read something about viewDidLoad / viewDidUnload methods of UIViewController class. These are called when your view is not "visible" (= unloaded) and loaded again. They help you to use memory efficiently. You should also look at memory warnings (didReceiveMemoryWarning method).

It's quite simple - in viewDidUnload, release everything what can be reconstructed in viewDidLoad method later. It helps you to keep memory footprint as small as possible.

Comment: First thanks for your suggestion Chiefly lzzy. As per your explanation the view will remains in the memory but we can remove all the objects inside that view. Am i correct?

Comment: lzzy Can i able to remove the particular view of the UINavigationController if i get memory warning or automatically UINavigationController will handle that if there is any memory warning. If i go back and forth between my pages did my memory grows or it will remains the same as it was in the first time?

Comment: Nope, if viewDidUnload is called, view no longer does exist, it's removed from memory and you should release all outlets, etc. here to free the memory. And to your second question - didReceiveMemoryWarning method is called on all UIViewControllers and you should release as much as possible memory or your application can be killed by the system.

Comment: If you go back and forth, your memory footprint will be +- same. When you go back, UINavigationController does release current view controller and if you go forth, you'll allocate it again, but it will be deallocated during going back, etc. Don't worry too much about memory management of UINavigationController, etc. As I wrote, focus yourself on viewDidLoad, viewDidUnload, didReceiveMemoryWarning and dealloc methods of your UIViewControllers to keep small memory footprint and don't worry about UINavigationController, etc.

Comment: lzzy Thanks a lot. Your words gives me a confident in using UINavigationController. I will give a try in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I am new iphone programming.  Still if you think this useful then use it.

You can use tab bar for your MAIN MENU. When user click on particular tab , user gets list of menus relevant to that page. After this when user selects any menu then new view is pushed. So it will minimize number of views pushed by 2. In this way you can come back to same menu using back button.

If you take proper precautions while allocating & deallocating memory used then there will be no issues of memory consumptions.

Comment: as i go for Tab bar for the menu and if i click on one menu i will see one page from there how can i navigate to another page within that tab itself? Moreover within that page there are another menus for that particular page. How should i navigate those menus? I had one more question will the tab bar will refresh its content whenever i click on the tabs?

Answer (score 0):

The utility template is a good start, you can add more 'flipVeiws' or load the original 'flipView' with different content depending on which button is pressed on your 'homepage'. This content could come from a plist array etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to find out how much memory is taken by ur app
struct task_basic_info info;
        mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
        kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                                       TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                                       (task_info_t)&info,
                                       &size);
        if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
            NSLog(@"Memory in use Root(in bytes): %u", info.resident_size);
        }
else {
            //NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
        }
Also Use didReceiveMemoryWarning method to find out wheather your app is crossing memory limit

Comment: i already done one app by using ViewBased model. I created every view and if i navigate from one view to another add it through subview. While adding to subview i use DismissModelViewController of the previous view. But if i navigate to and forth within different views the memory size goes on increasing. I released all objects from the previous view moreover i dismissed the previous view also. still memory grows. i cant retain the memory of that particular view once i come back from that view even if i released all objects and view. I didnt use any Screen transition also.No leaks found

Comment: Have u checked dealloc() method gets calling properly when u release an object?